# Envers: How to add a new column in *_AUD table (not in REVINFO table)

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-envers, audit-tables

For each audited entity, envers create a table with *_AUD suffix.

Each table has **TWO** extra columns ( **REV** and  **revtype**).

I just want to dynamically create a new one column to fulfill my extra needs.

Obs: Manually create the new column as a new filed in all entities does not fit to me.

Is that possibile?

Comment: What's the issue? Why `alter table mytable add column mycolumn` is not acceptable?

Comment: @DraganBozanovic I would like to do something like @ RevisionEntity, but for add dynamic fields/columns to audited entities table, not in REVINFO table.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to create a script and add the column you would like base on that:

```
spool c:\osama.log

select  'audit'||' ' || 'alter' || 'table' || ' '|| OWNER|| '.'||' '|| OBJECT_NAME|| ' '|| 'by access;' where owner='<user-name>';

Spool Off ;
```

See the rest of the page at this link: https://community.oracle.com/thread/2455981